# Effective way to populate listview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Everytime I click a different card an activity will be called like that EvsActivity.

But if no. of cards are 100 then i have to create 100 activity which is not a feasible solution.

so anybody with a better solution plz ur help will be appreciated

//Recyclerview with cardview code

```
package com.studyleague.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class AvailableContent extends TemplateFragment {
    @Bind(R.id.available_recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public AvailableContent() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.available_content, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);

        List<AvailableContentModel> content = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < AvailableContentData.acName.length; i++) {
            content.add(new AvailableContentModel(AvailableContentData.acIcon[i], AvailableContentData.acName[i]));
        }

        final AvailableContentAdapter contentAdapter = new AvailableContentAdapter(getActivity(), content);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contentAdapter);



        return v;

    }


}
```

//Adapter//

```
package com.studyleague.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class AvailableContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvailableContentAdapter.ContentViewHolder> {

    private final List<AvailableContentModel> dataSet;
    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<AvailableContentModel> content;

    public AvailableContentAdapter(Context context, List<AvailableContentModel> content) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataSet = content;
    }

    @Override
    public ContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.available_content_card, parent, false);
        return new ContentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContentViewHolder hold, final int listPosition) {
        hold.acImg.setImageResource(dataSet.get(listPosition).getContentImg());
        hold.acText.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getContentName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.available_card_image_view)
        ImageView acImg;
        @Bind(R.id.available_card_text_view)
        TextView acText;

        public ContentViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Mechanics", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "B. E. E.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Maths", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Chemistry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Physics", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, EvsActivity.class));
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "YOLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }


}
```

//Activity that is called when i click one of the card//

```
package com.studyleague.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class EvsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Bind(R.id.exp_list)
    ExpandableListView expListView;

    private List<String> chap;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_evs);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        // setting list adapter
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, chap, hashMap);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // expListView on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String groupName = chap.get(groupPosition);
                String childName = hashMap.get(groupName).get(childPosition);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), groupName + " : " + childName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Intent i = new Intent(EvsActivity.this, Study.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {

        // Hash map for both header and child
        hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Array list for header
        chap = new ArrayList<>();

        // Adding headers to list
        chap.add("1. Multidisciplinary Nature of Environmental Studies");
        chap.add("2. Sustainable Development");
        chap.add("3. Environmental Pollution");
        chap.add("4. Environmental Legislation");
        chap.add("5. Renewable Sources of Energy");
        chap.add("6. Environment and Technology");
        chap.add("7. Another Chapter");
        chap.add("8. Almost Another Chapter");

        // Array list for child items
        List<String> child1 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(1, 5));
        List<String> child2 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(2, 3));
        List<String> child3 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(3, 11));
        List<String> child4 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(4, 6));
        List<String> child5 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(5, 4));
        List<String> child6 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(6, 2));
        List<String> child7 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(7, 2));
        List<String> child8 = new ArrayList<>(fillChildData(8, 2));

        // Adding header and children to hash map
        hashMap.put(chap.get(0), child1);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(1), child2);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(2), child3);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(3), child4);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(4), child5);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(5), child6);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(6), child7);
        hashMap.put(chap.get(7), child8);
    }

    private Collection<String> fillChildData(int index, int n) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add("Group " + index + " - Child : " + (i + 1));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

//Code of data incase needed//

```
package com.studyleague.app;

public class AvailableContentData {

    static final Integer[] acIcon = {
            R.mipmap.mec,
            R.mipmap.elec,
            R.mipmap.mat,
            R.mipmap.chem,
            R.mipmap.ic,
            R.mipmap.env
    };
    static final String[] acName = {
            "Mechanics",
            "B. E. E.",
            "Maths",
            "Chemistry",
            "Physics",
            "E. V. S."
    };
}
```

Comment: This question is quite unclear. It would be better to show your code, clearly explain the problem you are having, including the outcome you expect and how that is not happening for you.

Comment: what is your goal?? may be you are following a wrong approach,please clarify what you want so we are able to help

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe and sam i have posted the code in answer plz have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Typed this up under the wrong account (cant comment, sorry), didn't stick I guess.  You create one Activity with one ListView and pass in the adapter that you want to use from the CardView intent.

Butterfly Cardview -> BUTTERFLY -> ButterflyAdapter

Baseball Bat Cardview -> BASEBALL -> BaseballBatAdatper

if your items are not related.  If they are related you can use the same adapter but send in a different layout based on what you sent in.

Butterfly -> R.layout.butterfly_items

Whale -> R.layout.whale_items